# How can I setup python3 in my WSL as an interpreter in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have downloaded Ubuntu for windows and it works fine however, when trying to setup a python environment for development using Ubuntu terminal as the interpreter for python I am having issues in figuring how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[WSL support in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/05/02/remote-development) just hit the insiders build of the editor!